# Blazor application logging with Serilog

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, serilog, asp.net-core-logging

In a blazor application I have start-up logging configured in **main** as follows;

```
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName();

            var appInsightsTelemetryConfiguration = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();
            appInsightsTelemetryConfiguration.InstrumentationKey = "aa11aa11aa-a1a1-a1-aa-a111-aa11";

            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore", Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Warning)
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .Enrich.WithProperty("Application", $"{assembly.Name}")
                .WriteTo.Console()          
                .WriteTo.Seq(serverUrl: "http://myseqserver.inthecloud.azurecontainer.io:5341/") 
                .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(appInsightsTelemetryConfiguration, TelemetryConverter.Traces)
                .CreateLogger();

            try
            {
                Log.Information(Constants.Logging.Messages.SERVICE_STARTED, assembly.Name);
                var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

                using (var serviceScope = host.Services.CreateScope())
                {
                    var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();
                    context.Database.Migrate(); // apply outstanding migrations automatically
                }

                host.Run();
                return;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Fatal(ex, Constants.Logging.Messages.SERVICE_STARTED, assembly.Name);
                return;
            }
            finally
            {
                // make sure all batched messages are written.
                Log.CloseAndFlush();
            }
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseSerilog()
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
```

and request logging in **StartUp** Configure;

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  //...
  services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry("aa11aa11aa-a1a1-a1-aa-a111-aa11");
  //...
}
        

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
      /// ...

            // Add this line; you'll need `using Serilog;` up the top, too
            app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            });
        }
```

On my blazor pages I cannot get this working;

```
@inject ILogger<ThisRazorPage> Logger

@code{
  protected override void OnInitialized()
  {
      Logger.LogTrace("Log something. Please!");
  }
}
```

But this does work;

```
@inject ILoggerFactory LoggerFactory

@code{
  protected override void OnInitialized()
  {
      var logger = LoggerFactory.CreateLogger<Incident>();
      logger.LogTrace("Log something. Please!");
  }
}
```

According to [this](https://andrewlock.net/adding-serilog-to-the-asp-net-core-generic-host/) the `.UseSerilog()` method adds the DI for `ILoggerFactory`. Is there a way for me to do something similar for `ILogger<T>` within the DI framework so that `ILogger<T>` can be used, rather than having to explicitly create a `LoggerFactory` on every page.

Comment: I have very much the same issue - mine is a server hosted (not wasm) and hence - console is the server console - not the browser console.

Answer (score 5):

You need:

- add `Serilog.Extensions.Logging`
- add in your Main()

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
    builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
  
    // ...
            
    builder.Services.AddTransient<AccountsViewModel>();


    var levelSwitch = new LoggingLevelSwitch();
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.ControlledBy(levelSwitch)
        .Enrich.WithProperty("InstanceId", Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n"))
        .CreateLogger();

    // ------------- this is what you'r looking for
    builder.Logging.AddSerilog();

    // ...

    await builder.Build().RunAsync();
}
```

- and in your ViewModel

```
public class AccountsViewModel
{
    private readonly ILogger<AccountsViewModel> Logger;
    private readonly HttpClient Http;

    public AccountsViewModel(
        ILogger<AccountsViewModel> logger,
        HttpClient http
        )
    {
        Http = http;
        Logger = logger;

        Logger.LogInformation("AccountsViewModel()");
    }
}
```

- or in your razor-page:

```
@inject ILogger<ThisRazorPage> logger;
```

Comment: I cannot make it work. Did everything like here.

Answer (score 3):

Static method works for me.

```
@using Serilog


@code {
    Log.Information("Log something. Please!");
}
```

Comment: Put the "@using Serilog" into your _Imports.razor and you don't need to write it in your .razor files everytime. When you're using code behind files (xyz.razor.cs) instead you need to provide the using directive. Taking care of this the solution from Adam works for me, too. However, it is a condition that the use of Serilog has been implemented as documented on Serilogs homepage.