# .net Maui Blazor unable to inject Serilog

Tags: .net, serilog, blazor-webassembly, maui, maui-blazor

Goal:
Implement Serilog into a .net Maui Blazor app using dependency injection.

I am able to get the static method in the MauiProgram.cs file to log properly, but I am unable to log anywhere else in the app.

I have tried various set ups as indicated in these docs, https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging

I also tried the .net Blazor (not Maui) solution reported here, but to no avail: [Blazor application logging with Serilog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64790313/blazor-application-logging-with-serilog)

I added

```
using Serilog;
```

to my imports.razor.

I have tried:

```
builder.Services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder => 
    loggingBuilder.AddSerilog(Log.Logger, dispose: true));
```

And:

```
builder.Logging.AddSerilog(Log.Logger, dispose: true);
```

**MauiProgram.cs:**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Maui;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Maui.Hosting;
using SortedDesktop.Data;
using MudBlazor.Services;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Events;
using System;

namespace Desktop
{
public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
         Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
        .MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Warning)
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
        .WriteTo.Seq("http://adomain.com")
        .CreateLogger();

        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();

        builder
            .RegisterBlazorMauiWebView()
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
            });

        builder.Services.AddBlazorWebView();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();          
        builder.Services.AddMudServices();

        //builder.Services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder => 
        //    loggingBuilder.AddSerilog(Log.Logger, dispose: true));

        builder.Logging.AddSerilog(Log.Logger, dispose: true);

        try
        {
            Log.Information("Starting desktop app");
            return builder.Build();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Fatal(ex, "Host terminated unexpectedly");
        }
        finally
        {
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }

        return builder.Build();

    }
}
}
```

As I mentioned, the static call above to Log.Information works fine here.

**Razor page**

```
@inject ILogger<AddJob> logger;

@code {
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    logger.LogInformation("Add Job initialized");
    Log.Information("Add Job initialized (static method call)");
}
}
```

Neither of the calls above work.

Comment: This issue is related to MAUI. You could post in GutHub.https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues

Answer (score 0):

The library Serilog-Ilogger-Blazor worked for me on Maui

https://github.com/pablopioli/serilog-ilogger-blazor

It was built for Blazor but it also works on Maui